# Как использовать «Case when» в «after update» триггере?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, update, триггер

У меня есть "update" триггер который выглядит вот так:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Removal_add` BEFORE UPDATE ON `post_cost` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
SET NEW.Removal_pl = ((CASE WHEN (SELECT `Poli_csl` FROM slid WHERE slid.id = NEW.id)<10 THEN 
 (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 0.3 
 ELSE (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) END));
END
```

Этот триггер у меня работает.
Но я еще хочу создать триггер "after update" с этим же условием из триггера выше, но не знаю как это сделать, пока что выдает ошибку.

Сам триггер after update:

```
CREATE TRIGGER post_2
    AFTER UPDATE
    ON slid FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN 
UPDATE `harld`.`post_cost` SET `Removal_pl` = CASE WHEN NEW.`Poli_csl`  WHERE `id` = NEW.id < 10 THEN
 (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 0.3 
 ELSE (SELECT `Model_R_Hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT `Time_hr` FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) END));
END;
```

Что не так? Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: если вы хотите точно такое же условие, то почему пишите совершенно другое, синтаксически неверное. В первом случае у вас подзапрос `CASE WHEN (SELECT Poli_csl FROM slid WHERE slid.id = NEW.id)<10 THEN ....` обратите внимание, WHERE относится к этому запросу, а не к case. А во втором случае почему то `CASE WHEN NEW.Poli_csl  WHERE id = NEW.id < 10` куда потерялся select, что означает фраза where в составе case, если ее там быть не может в принципе

Comment: А еще обратите внимание, что во втором триггере у самого update нет своего where и если бы ошибки не было, он бы переписал все записи в таблице, что вы вероятно не планировали

Comment: А так же обратите внимание, что `(SELECT Model_R_Hr FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id) * 
 (SELECT Time_hr FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id)` можно было бы написать как `(SELECT Model_R_Hr * Time_hr FROM rate WHERE rate.id = NEW.id)` что не только короче, но и в 2 раза быстрее

Comment: Но ведь в этом ```after update```  не должен использоваться ```select```  в первой строчке, по крайней мере другие ```after update``` триггеры я писал без ```select```  и они работали.

Comment: конечно не должен, но что означает WHERE ? синтаксис case: `case WHEN условие THEN значение ELSE значение END` где тут WHERE ?

Comment: почему не написать просто `case when NEW.Poli_csl < 10 THEN ...`